# Updating Property on Object with MongoDB Without Wiping Out Surrounding Properties

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a Node/MongoDB backend endpoint that takes a passed in an array of mongo _ids, and then updates a field on the records matching those passed in ids.

```
if (mongoArrRecords) {
    try {
        db.collection('clients').updateMany(
            { _id: { $in: mongoArrRecords } },
            { $set: { subscription: { subscriptionEnd: lastDayOfMonth } } },
            function (err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(res);
            });
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

}
```

However, what I'm noticing is is that rather than merely updating the property I'm defining with the `$set` operator, the entire containing object is being wiped out and replaced with this one property.

The data being targeted looks like this (subscription) is an array at the root of the document:

```
   "subscription": [
        {
            "someProp": value,
            "someOtherProp": value,
            "subscriptionEnd": "2017-04-30T05:00:00.000Z",
        }
    ],
```

So my question is: how I can make this update just the field in question, without wiping out the surrounding properties within the object? Because right now, after making my update, the above data looks like this (notice "someProp" and "someOtherProp" are now gone):

```
   "subscription": [
        {
            "subscriptionEnd": "2018-04-30T05:00:00.000Z",
        }
    ],
```

If I can't target precisely, the only other option I can imagine is getting the object first, and passing back in that entire object -- though I'm not sure exactly what that would look like. Surely there must be a way to change one property on one object within an array? Yes? No?

Comment: what is your mongo server version ? how do you pick which array element to update ?

Comment: Whatever _ids match the passed in _ids get updated. And yes, I also need to solve identifying which array element to update. One problem at a time :).

Comment: so you would like to update specifc property for all array elements ? if no, what is the search criteria for picking an array element ? Also version please.

Comment: Before you acces the document it could not now if there is a sub field called "subscription" or not. Can you try to change your $set part like $set : {"subscription.subscriptionEnd":lastDayOfMonth}

Comment: Ah, I see, so if I wrap the property chain in quotes it will work. Was wondering about that. Okay, trying this now. Thanks.

Comment: Will this replace the property for all found elements in the array, or do I need to target the array element specifically for it to work -- like {"subscription[0].subscriptionEnd":lastDayOfMonth} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`positional all` $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) to target all array elements in 3.6.

```
db.collection('clients').updateMany( 
 { _id: { $in: mongoArrRecords } },
 { $set: { "subscription.$[].subscriptionEnd": lastDayOfMonth } }
)
```

Target specific element ( 1st element )

```
db.collection('clients').updateMany( 
 { _id: { $in: mongoArrRecords } },
 { $set: { "subscription.0.subscriptionEnd": lastDayOfMonth } }
)
```

Target element through query filter [`dynamically`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

```
db.collection('clients').updateMany( 
 { _id: { $in: mongoArrRecords }, "subscription.someOtherProp":value},
 { $set: { "subscription.$.subscriptionEnd": lastDayOfMonth } }
)
```

Comment: Much appreciated @Veeram.